# Epiphany browser open URLs in the same tab in python

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, epiphany

I am using epiphany webbrowser in my Raspberry Pi project. According to the requirement I need to open a link on the same tab using python webbrowser module. But each time a new tab is opened although I've given the parameter new=0

```
import webbrowser
import time
b = webbrowser.get('epiphany')
b.open('http://www.google.com', new=0)
time.sleep(5)
b.open('https://stackoverflow.com', new=0)
```

Any way to resolve this? I need to open urls on the same tab. Any solution from the webbrowser's perspective or python webbrowser module's perspective is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem with epiphany, get yourself firefox(iceweasel) for raspbian(is anyway quicker):

```
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
```

then you need to install selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

i tested this snippet on pi2+:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ['http://192.168.0.1', 'http://192.168.0.2','http://192.168.0.3']

b = webdriver.Firefox()

while True:
    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
        b.maximize_window()
        b.get(url)
        sleep(20)
```

the only issue is that it opens an new window once and then loads your urls in the same tab, if that's good enough for you.

Comment: tnx for the alternative, but I need to keep my memory and cpu usage low.